# Difference between fread() & fwrite() while using fseek()?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm currently working on a problem in CS50x, I have to reverse a existing WAV file and make it into a new one. I've been able to tackle all other TODOs (I think) but using fopen, fwrite and fseek is causing me a headache. Here's the code I wrote:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < iterateCount; i++)
    {
        fseek(input, -blockSize * (i + 1), SEEK_END);
        fseek(output, headerSize + blockSize * i, SEEK_SET);

        // copy & paste
        fread(&buffer, blockSize, 1, input);
        fwrite(&buffer, blockSize, 1, output);
    }
```

So, what the code's trying to do is iterating over the original file(aka "input") and copy & pasting over the new file(aka "output").

This code works JUST FINE actually, but when I searched for more information about the problem so I can found something to improve in efficiency, people seemed to not use `fseek()` with *output*.
I thought I had to iterate over not only *input* but also *output* too because if I didn't, fwrite would write the new information to the same location over and over again. Or is it??

My question is, does `fwrite()` have the feature same to `fseek()` by itself?

I removed the `fseek()` for *output* and it indeed worked fine.

Comment: You don't need the seeks. You are already positioned at the right place in both cases, every time. You have no basis for your belief that `fwrite()` will keep writing to the same position. It doesn't. You should also use as large a `blocksize` as possible: nothing mingy like 512 bytes. Maybe even 1Mb.

Comment: @user20742, Re "*You should also use as large a `blocksize` as possible*", That's true for unbuffered reads and writes (`read` and `write`), but not for buffered reads and writes (`fread` and `fwrite`).

Comment: @ikegami It's true for both. The default buffersize for `stdio` is pathetically small, 4k or 8k. As a matter of fact there's no good reason to use `stdio` here at all, just `read()` and `write()`.

Comment: BOTH `fread()` and `fwrite()` _keep track_ of where they are in their respective files... You don't need `fseek()` when writing sequential blocks of output. You do need `fseek()` if you want to read "blocks" from the end of the file toward the beginning... (BTW: reading/writing and seeking can fail. You should be verifying the return values from those functions!)

Comment: And so do `read()` and `write()`, and every other sequential I/O API ever designed, by definition. It's the operating system doing this, not `fread()` and `fwrite()`.

Comment: @user207421: The seeks on the input file cannot be omitted. `fseek(input, -blockSize * (i + 1), SEEK_END);` causes the reads to be done from positions in reverse order, and this is frame an exercise to time-reverse the audio in a wave file. The input seeks are necessary. Also, the block size cannot be changed. It is not used for buffering; it is a structural size of the wave file—it is one multi-channel audio sample, calculated as the number of channels multiplied by the bytes per channel. The reversal operation must be done in units of that block size.

Comment: @ikegami: @user207421: The seeks on the input file cannot be omitted. `fseek(input, -blockSize * (i + 1), SEEK_END);` causes the reads to be done from positions in reverse order, and this is frame an exercise to time-reverse the audio in a wave file. The input seeks are necessary.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Very good but I don't find that stated in the original question. It would have helped.

Comment: @user207421: The first sentence of the question says “…  I have to reverse a existing WAV file…” The input seek offset is given with a minus sign.

Comment: @user207421 *It doesn't. You should also use as large a blocksize as possible: nothing mingy like 512 bytes. Maybe even 1Mb*  When reading a file by **reverse** seeking through it?  In this case, using a buffer no larger than strictly necessary would be the best choice.  And once you hit about 8k buffer sizes, there's little performance left to be gained from larger `FILE *`-based buffers because the page cache will dominate.  Once you get into using direct IO to bypass the page cache, then the IO pattern better match the underlying hardware or performance will be execrable.

Comment: You DO NOT have to `seek()` anything. The wav header provides all the size information needed to read the header and data, compute the block-size and then simply reverse the data in block-size chunks. It's easiest to simply read the header -- then read `header.subchunk2Size` bytes into a buffer -- make a copy of the buffer (or just swap blocks) -- and reverse the data in block-size chunks. Then simply write the header and reversed data to the output file. NO `seek()` involved.

Comment: Here is a [Quick Hack Reversing Without seek()](https://godbolt.org/z/s1a41fTE5) - NOTE there are two `reverse_blocks()` functions provided. The first using a copy of the entire `data` section to reverse, the second if `LOWMEM` is defined uses only a `block-size` temporary buffer to swap the blocks of data (but uses 1/3 more `memcpy()` calls). Just another approach to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> people seemed to not use `fseek()` with *output*. I thought I had to iterate over not only *input* but also *output* too because if I didn't, fwrite would write the new information to the same location over and over again. Or is it??

No, that is not the case.

You seem to understand that the system maintains a sense of a current position in each stream (file).  `fseek()` is one way to modify that.  But successfully reading from or writing to a stream also modifies its file position.  They advance it by the number of bytes transferred, which is almost always what you want.  If the file is not manually repositioned then the next read just picks up where the last one left off.  For writes without repositioning, the next write starts immediately after the last byte written, or (always) at the end of the file if it is open in append mode.  It's more complicated if you're both reading and writing the same file, but that's not your case.

> My question is, does `fwrite()` have the feature same to `fseek()` by itself?

That's an odd way to put it.  `fseek()` is by far the exception, not the rule.  Many programs do I/O without ever calling `fseek()`.  The `fwrite()` function does update the file position, as already discussed, but few people would characterize that as `fwrite()` performing an `fseek()`.  Some files are not even seekable -- the only way to change their file positions is by reading from them or writing to them.  `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` often have this characteristic, for example.

> I removed the `fseek()` for *output* and it indeed worked fine.

As I would expect.  Overall, the section of code presented writes a contiguous section of the output file, starting at the beginning of that section and continuing in order to the end.  That doesn't require any seeking, and it would be better to omit the `fseek()`s on this file for clarity and to reduce the cross section for bugs.

The situation for the reads is different -- you are reading, blockwise, from end to beginning, so after each block you are not automatically at the start position for the next read. You do need to reposition (via `fseek()`) in that case.

Answer (score 2):

C 2018 7.21.8.2 specifies the `fwrite` function, and paragraph 2 says:

> … The file position indicator for the stream (if defined) is advanced by the number of characters successfully written…

Therefore, no seeks for ordinary traversal through a file are required.

For the reads, you do need the seeks, since you are reversing the data.

Ignore the comments saying that seeks on the reads were not needed, as they neglected the fact the data is being reversed. Also ignore the comments to change the buffer size, as they were made in ignorance of the fact that the block size is set to the size of one multi-channel audio sample, rather than being used to buffer for performance.